# convert string to object key more than 2depths

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string to object's key

I know this logic

```
const object = { name : 'test' }
const string = name
object[string] = name
```

I have something problems about this.

```
const string = common.device.type.pc.name
```

object[string] <- this is not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: Try to add a bit more context to your question

Comment: What is your source string?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by split string to each value
`values = string.split(".");
object[values[0]][values[1]][values[2]][values[3]][values[4]]`

Example:
`object = {value1: {value2: "123"}};
string = "value1.value2";
values = string.split(".");
object[values[0]][values[1]] //return "123"`